# infopath printing in sharepoint

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2007, infopath-2007

Can any one explain how to print the infopath data in sharepoint

Comment: Infopath Services include Printing functionality?! Just click the print button. Also what version of InfoPath, what version of Sharepoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Form is posted in a Form Library AND you have made InfoPath fields available as columns in Form Library, you can add them your your active view, sort them, set page size, export them to excel, or print from there on. You have to promote properties to columns from InfoPath designer. If not already done so for the published template, you need the orignal template, and design it in InfoPath designer.

If columns are not available, you still have form data available in XML and things might take different routes depending where you want to go.

You can programatically read xml of all infopath forms in the form library, apply search filters, do XSLT and generate HTML files, you can set page size or directly send to printer.

You can also use templating techniques if you have a template.

Comment: I created the form library and attached the infopath template to that library. I am trying to open xml files in formlibraries inside the browser. It is saying "Session state not activated". So what i need to do is 1)Opening form library files inside the browser.   2)Printing the form library files directly using c sharp code.  Please help me in the above two cases.

Comment: Does your template uses custom code? And is Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents for your Form Library set to 'Open in browser?'

Comment: yes. i made it as to 'Open in browser'. It is saying Session State not activated".

Comment: 1. Have you written C#/VB code for your template? 2. You get a message about session state because, session state for InfoPath form services is not configured on your server... To do that follow these steps http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262263.aspx#session

Comment: I wrote my infopath form coding in C#. I am using Sharepoint 2007, MS office 2007 and Visual Studio 2010.